# Cross platform: Debugging using WSL under Windows fails when using shared dynamic libraries using Visual Studio 2019

Tags: debugging, libraries, visual-studio-2019, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have a project consisting of a few libraries which is cross platform and runs and debugs just fine if all the source code is in one Visual Studio 2019 project. However, having the libraries in separate projects and I cannot debug from within the IDE at all.  However, the executable will run perfectly ok from the command line in my WSL installation and on other Linux boxes. I have tried various things such as setting my LD_LIBRARY_PATH as one of the projects is a shared dynamic library, but nothing so far seems to work. Anyone have any ideas on this ? Thanks

Update: if I manually copy the dynamic library e.g.

cp libWSI.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libWSI.so

debugging works. But this is not ideal.

The output I get from the Debugger is this:

`=thread-group-added,id="i1"
GNU gdb (Ubuntu 8.1-0ubuntu3.1) 8.1.0.20180409-git
Copyright (C) 2018 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-linux-gnu".
Type "show configuration" for configuration details.
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/.
Find the GDB manual and other documentation resources online at:
http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/documentation/.
For help, type "help".
Type "apropos word" to search for commands related to "word".
=cmd-param-changed,param="pagination",value="off"
Stopped due to shared library event (no libraries added or removed)
Loaded '/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2'. Symbols loaded.
[Inferior 1 (process 1438) exited with code 0177]
The thread 'WSITests.out' (0x59e) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The program '' has exited with code 177 (0xb1).`

Comment: Hi, do you get any error when the debugging failed?

Comment: Hi I've just added the output from the debugger to the bottom of the post. Thanks for reponding

Answer (score 0):

My debugger won`t start even with the libs in the same folder when using dynamic linking. I have found a workaround here: https://github.com/Microsoft/VSLinux/issues/257

You have to make a script, let`s say "debug.sh", where you add the paths to your lib folders and run the debugger with --interpreter=mi argument. I suspect this gdb argument does the magic in this case.

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/mnt/c/Users/mircea.goga/source/repos/TestCoreCLRLinux/Out/
/usr/bin/gdb --interpreter=mi
```

In Visual Studio, set the path to this file to "Remote GDB Path" in "Debugging" section.
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lkel9.png)